# python: how to use a variable (time_convert)of a class (stopwatch)in other python3 script

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class stopwatch(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global time_convert,time_convert1,draw,start_time,padding,padding_2,top,top_2,x,x_2,font,font_2,image,width,height
        #self.width = width
       # self.height = height
        #self.image = image
        #self.draw = draw
        #self.padding = padding
        #self.padding_2 = padding_2
       # self.top = top
        #self.top_2 = top_2
       # self.font = font
       # self.font_2 = font_2
    def main():
        global time_convert,time_convert1,draw,start_time,padding,padding_2,top,top_2,x,x_2,font,font_2,image,width,height
        global flag
        flag = True #flag = True #flag x ciclo while
    #reset display
        disp.begin()
        disp.clear()
        disp.display()
    #preparazione display con immagine vuota
        width = disp.width
        height = disp.height
        image = Image.new('1', (width, height))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        draw.rectangle((0,0,width,height), outline=0, fill=0)
    #ridimensionamento caratteri padding= alza/abbassa carattere, x= destra/sinistra carattere
        padding = 0
        padding_2 = 3.5 # per carattere decimali più piccolo
        top = padding
        top_2 = padding_2 # per carattere decimali più piccolo
        x = 10
        x_2 = 75 # per carattere decimali più piccolo
        
        font = ImageFont.truetype('/home/albe/Documents/Progetti/schiuma150/Calculator.ttf',30)
        font_2 =ImageFont.truetype('/home/albe/Documents/Progetti/schiuma150/Calculator.ttf',20)
        #print("Press button red to start and green to stop")
        #GPIO.wait_for_edge(23,GPIO.FALLING)
        #print("crono iniziato")
    #def run():
     #   global time_convert,time_convert1,draw,start_time,padding,padding_2,top,top_2,x,x_2,font,font_2,image,width,height
      #  flag = True
        start_time = time.time()
        while (flag):
            #global time_convert,time_convert1,draw,start_time,padding,padding_2,top,top_2,x,x_2,font,font_2,image,width,height
            #global flag
            current_time = time.time()
            timer = current_time - start_time
            sec =  int (timer)
            decs = math.modf(timer)
            decs1 = int (decs[0]*60) #parte decimale
            sec1 = int(sec % 60)
            mins = int(sec // 60)
        #hour = int(mins // 60)
        #time_convert ="{:02n}:{:02n}:{:02n}:".format(hour,mins,sec1)#creazione indice x formattazione
            time_convert ="{:02n}':{:02n}'':".format(mins,sec1)#creazione indice x formattazione
            time_convert1 ="{}".format(decs1) # per carattere decimali più piccolo
            return time_convert
            return main.time_convert1
            draw.text((x, top),str(time_convert),font=font,fill=255), draw.text((x_2, top_2),str(time_convert1),font=font_2,fill=255)
            disp.image(image)
            disp.display()
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
            draw.rectangle((0,0,width,height), outline=0, fill=0)
            #print("crono run")
            #x = 0
            #cam = os.popen("./vcmipidemo-pi3 -i 1 -s 2180250 -g 0x88 -o && mv img00000.pgm /home/albe/Documents/Progetti/schiuma150/test_images/all_img/img"+str(x)+".pgm")
            #time.sleep(1)
            #img = Image.open("/home/albe/Documents/Progetti/schiuma150/test_images/all_img/img"+str(x)+".pgm")
            #x +=1
            #draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
            #font = ImageFont.truetype("Calculator.ttf", 25)
            #draw.text((500, 350), text= str('Timer: ' + time_convert + time_convert1) ,fill=255,font=font)
            #img.save('/home/albe/Documents/Progetti/schiuma150/test_images/results/img'+str(x)+'stamp.pgm')
           # print("image saved")
        else:
            exit()
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: `time_convert` doesn't seem to be a variable of a class, since you are using `global`, so it's a global variable. To make is a variable of the class stopwatch you need use `self.time_convert`

Comment: thanks, but the point I don't understand, which is the way to call time_convert from a script where is imported stopwatch

Comment: that will depend if it's a class variable or global. if its global just import it, otherwise you will have to instantiate the class.

Comment: here is a basic guide on how to use classes:  https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp